# Making a dot animation in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

The problem is straightforward but I am beginner in python and stuck on the optimal way to implement this:

- I have a .txt file that contains time (s) and frequency.
- I want a visualization of this data as a dot moving up and down a vertical axis.
- I need the dot to move at the corresponding time stamp of the frequency, since I plan to output an mp4 file and sync up the animation to the original sound file.
- The max and min of the y axis would be those of the frequency in the file.

By "moving" I think making the dot appear and disappear before the next one should work, so it's not continuous.
Below is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Import Data
time = np.loadtxt("sentence 1.txt", usecols=0, skiprows=1, dtype=float)
print(time)
print(time.shape)
f0 = np.loadtxt("sentence 1.txt", usecols=1, skiprows=1, dtype=float)
print(f0)
print(f0.shape)

# These are the indices of onset times of syllables
# time[0], time[10], time[22], time[34], time[85], time[100]


onset = [0,10,22,34,85,100]

# Do f0 averages for each syllable and create an array

def utterances(array):
  f0_mean = []
  end = 0
  for i in range(len(array)):
    if i == len(array)-1:
      end = len(f0) - 1
    else:
      end = array[i+1]-1
    avg = np.mean(f0[array[i]:end])
    f0_mean.append(avg)
  return f0_mean

utterance = utterances(onset)
print(utterance)
print(min(f0), max(f0))
```

Is there a way to handle specific times in seconds (for example [0.15     0.160714 0.171429 0.182143 0.192857 0.203571 0.214286 0.225
0.235714 0.246429]) in the matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()?

Comment: There is no question in your question. See [ask], how to create a [mcve] for whatever specific problem you are having with the [tag:python] language. Edit the question.

Comment: `FuncAnimation` uses "frames" which always have the same time. Maybe use `time.sleep()` for this - without `FuncAnimation`.